# Netbeans C project configuration needed to compile

Tags: c, netbeans, time

In this program that I am trying to compile & run in Netbeans, I am using `clock_gettime` function which is **not** part of the C standard:

```
#include <time.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  struct timespec now;
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &now);
  return 0;
}
```

Apart from the `#include <time.h>` part, I should do a configuration in Netbeans to compile & run it but I don't know which one to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved changing the C compiler type.

With the error I used to have:

> Properties -> Build -> C Compiler -> C Standard -> **C99**

And changing to this solved it:

> Properties -> Build -> C Compiler -> C Standard -> **Default**